# How do I combine various factors/variables to a single factor/variable

Tags: machine-learning, mathematical-statistics, data-visualization, cross-validation, structural-equation-modeling

I have various products and for each product I have 5 types of cost(not just monetary cost) variables associated with it, the value of each variable for any product is a positive integer.
I want to combine all these together to come with a composite score (which will be derived by combining the individual scores of 6 fields for each application) giving function, use it to assign a composite score to each product and then use that score to compare the products over a period of time.
I am a newbie to data science problem, I have a deadline coming so I can't study everything and then come up with a solution, can structural equation modelling be applied here?
A sample case (one month's data)

### suppose I have 5 products A,B,C,D,E and 6 factors F1,F2,...F5

[image]

I want to compare these products and want to combine the individual score of every factor for each product to come up with a total score and then use that score to compare the products relative to each other at this time instant.
Please suggest me if there is some standard way of approaching the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with factor analysis. The basic idea is that each of the items loads onto a lower dimensional set of factors. You can do this in `R` with the `lavaan` package with something like:

```
model = "general =~ F1 + F2 + F3 + F4 + F5"
fit = cfa(model, data)
```

Then to get the factor scores, you can use
`predict(fit)` . Note you'll have to pay special attention to the type of estimator that you use when you fit the model, as well as the model specification. Here is the lavaan documentation (http://lavaan.ugent.be/) .

Comment: hey I know R but I havent used Lavaan so far, what I want to know is that will I be able to get individual score for each product as I need?

Comment: If each row is a product, then yes, the factor scores will correspond to individual scores for each product. The units may not have much meaning though.

Comment: hey can you help me interpret the result? I mean how do I find the factor scores you mentioned, what I am aiming at is combining the individual factor score for each product and then use it to compare the products with each other, how do I get that score, please suggest..thanks